# python2.7: not found: Unable to install or remove any packages

Tags: apt, python

I am currently unable to install any packages. At first it started with complaints that it couldn't find `/usr/bin/python` (not 100% sure of the path here) so I tried to re-install python using synaptic. The re-install failed as well.

Now, I cannot access the side bar in Unity and no keyboard short-cuts work. I can access Chrome by right-clicking a file and selecting "Open with..." and access the command line using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f#</kbd> but that is about all.

I did `sudo apt-get install` with the results:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apturl : Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2)
 gwibber : Depends: libgwibber-gtk2 (>= 3.1.4.1+r1119) but it is not installed
    Depends: libgwibber2 (>= 3.1.4.1) but it is not installed
 ibus : Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2)
 libgksu2-0 : Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2)
 update-manager : Depends: gksu but it is not installed
```

and `sudo apt-get -f install` with the results:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkspell0 liblaunchpad-integration1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gconf2 gksu gwibber gwibber-service language-selector-common
  language-selector-gnome libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2
Suggested packages:
  gconf-defaults-service gwibber-service-flickr gwibber-service-digg
  gwibber-service-statusnet gwibber-service-foursquare
  gwibber-service-friendfeed gwibber-service-pingfm gwibber-service-qaiku
  unity-lens-gwibber
Recommended packages:
  gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-twitter gwibber-service-identica
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gconf2 gksu libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gwibber gwibber-service language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/866 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,281 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Setting up python-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst: python2.7: not found
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
```

Any help would be great. Seems like I'm 100% screwed.

I checked my `/usr/bin directory`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nolando nolando 9 Apr 17  2012 python -> python2.7  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nolando nolando 9 Apr 17  2012 python2 -> python2.7
```

I am using Using 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, something has gone terribly wrong unpacking your python .deb. Try `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal*deb` and see if that fixes the dpkg error.

Comment: Tried this with the python-minimal_2.7.3*deb archive but it failed.

Comment: What's the error you get? If it's the same we can go one level deeper, to make it just unpack (which should restore `/usr/bin/python2.7`): `sudo dpkg --unpack thatfile.deb`

Comment: Error is:  
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.potinst: python2.7: not found,  
  
and then goes on to say it returned an error code of 127.

Comment: sudo dpkg --unpack thatfile.deb completes successfully.

Comment: Going to reinstall, thanks for taking a shot at this.

Comment: it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1721421 was solved by reinstall as python has wide dependencies.

but try solution from this forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1425619, it could be just about python config and versions

try `/usr/bin/python` and if the result is weird give us a note or try to look for python manually. Maybe the symlink would be enough.

Comment: I checked my /usr/bin directory:  
  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nolando nolando 9 Apr 17  2012 python -> python2.7    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nolando nolando 9 Apr 17  2012 python2 -> python2.7  
  
I keep getting no file or directory when I run /usr/bin/python.